# How do you return an array object in java?

Tags: java, oop

How do you return an array object in Java? I have an object that has an array in it and I want to work with it in my main class:

```
// code that does not work
class obj()
{
  String[] name;
  public obj()
  {
    name = new string[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      name[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }
  }
  public String[] getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
}

public class maincl
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    obj one = new obj();
    system.out.println(one.getName());
  }
```

I am sorry if the answer is simple but I am teaching myself to code and I have no idea how you would do this.

Comment: What error message are you getting, if I may ask?

Comment: By returning an array, as your `getName()` method already does.

Comment: You say that your code don't work, could you be more accurate ? What don't work ? Have you an exception ?

Comment: Hi there, you're already returning an array in getName.

Comment: Please note that in Java, all class names should start with a capital letter. So `obj` should be `Obj`, or preferably a more descriptive name. The same is true for `maincl`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `toString` method.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one.getName()));
```

[`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean%5B%5D%29) is a built-in function in Java (it might need library import; if you are using Netbeans, it will suggest it).

Comment: Yes, but the output would be ugly (e.g. `[foo, bar, baz]`).

Comment: ok, I usually use import java.util.*; I will see if that takes care of this

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to print it use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one.getName()));
```

//note `System`, not `system`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `getName()` you are returning a reference to an array of strings, not the strings themselves. In order to access the individual strings entered, you can use the array index 
`String enteredName = name[index]` format.

From your program, it looks like you want to print each item entered. For that, you could use a method like the following

```
  public void printName() {
      // for each item in the list of time
      for(String enteredName : name) {

        // print that entry
        System.out.println(enteredName);
      }
  }
```